# Neat way to determine element id when only predecessor and successor ids are known - Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I got the following situation:
My input data contains several elements with a predecessor and successor id - but not its own id.
It looks like the following table

```html
+----------+-------------+-------------+
| Element  | NextBlockID | PrevBlockID |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
| Block623 | c308002017  | 2a08003017  |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
| Block625 | 0           | c308002017  |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
| Block622 | 2808003017  | c208002017  |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
| Block620 | c208002017  | 0           |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
| Block621 | 2a08003017  | be08003017  |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
| Block624 | 2908002017  | 2808003017  |
+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

Now I want to determine the element id of each element and add it as a new column.
What I am doing right now is determinating the first element where PrevBlockID is zero. Afterwards lookup where the NextBlockID of my first element matches PrevBlockID of another one and add it to a list with all eager element ids of Block622,Block624, ... until there is no more match for NextBlockID.
Then I look at the element having NextBlockID = 0. This is the last element. Where its value PrevBlockID matches a NextBlockID I get the uneager element ids (of Block623, Block621) one by one

So afterwards I want an output table like this

```html
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Element  | NextBlockID | PrevBlockID | ElementID  |
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Block623 | c308002017  | 2a08003017  | 2808003017 |
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Block625 | 0           | c308002017  | 2908002017 |
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Block622 | 2808003017  | c208002017  | 2a08003017 |
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Block620 | c208002017  | 0           | be08003017 |
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Block621 | 2a08003017  | be08003017  | c208002017 |
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Block624 | 2908002017  | 2808003017  | c308002017 |
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

My input data is stored in a panda dataframe. Is there any smarter/quicker solution then iterating through the values one by one?

update 2020/06/14 2:07pm:
Sorry for the confusion here is the code I got so far:

```
import pandas as pd
f1 = 'DF_DetermineBlockID.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(f1, sep=';')
Ids = pd.Series([], dtype=object)
df = df.sort_values("PrevBlock")  # sorted to get 0 value in first pos
df.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(df.index))

successor = df[df.index == 0].squeeze()["NextBlock"]
Ids = Ids.append(pd.Series(successor, index=[1]))
a = 1
PrevBlockFound = not df[df["PrevBlock"] == successor].empty

while PrevBlockFound:
    a += 2
    successor = df[df["PrevBlock"] == successor].squeeze()["NextBlock"]
    Ids = Ids.append(pd.Series(successor, index=[a]))
    PrevBlockFound = not df[df["PrevBlock"] == successor].empty

predecessor = df[df["NextBlock"] == "0"].squeeze()["PrevBlock"]
a -= 1
Ids = Ids.append(pd.Series(predecessor, index=[a]))
NextBlockFound = not df[df["NextBlock"] == predecessor].empty

while NextBlockFound:
    a -= 2
    predecessor = df[df["NextBlock"] == predecessor].squeeze()["PrevBlock"]
    Ids = Ids.append(pd.Series(predecessor, index=[a]))
    NextBlockFound = not df[df["NextBlock"] == predecessor].empty

df = pd.merge(df, Ids.rename('BlockID'), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a little difficult to figure out the logic you're looking for - but this code produces the output you're expecting:

```
df = df.sort_values("Element")
df["ElementID"] = df.PrevBlockID.shift(-1)
df.loc[df.ElementID.isna(), "ElementID"] = df.NextBlockID.shift()
df.sort_index(inplace = True)
```

The output is:

```
    Element NextBlockID PrevBlockID   ElementID
0  Block623  c308002017  2a08003017  2808003017
1  Block625           0  c308002017  2908002017
2  Block622  2808003017  c208002017  2a08003017
3  Block620  c208002017           0  be08003017
4  Block621  2a08003017  be08003017  c208002017
5  Block624  2908002017  2808003017  c308002017
```

Comment: Does this do what you were looking for?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. The shift command is pretty handy here. It's kind of what I'm looking for. It works and creates the output I want, but unfortunately I can't rely on the Element column to be in the correct order. There could be any free strings in it. My data excerpt was a bad example of mine probably. Is there any way to do this without the element column?

Comment: If you iterate things, you must have some order. What's the order you'd like to use? In other words, what's the' predecessor and successor ' you mention in the title of the post? More generally, it would be great if you could explain the logic of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi Roy, I edited my initial post and put my code there. I don't want any specific order afterwards. What I got is external data with information about blocks that are linked to each other. So each block is following another with a predecessor (PrevBlockID) and successor (NextBlockID). The Block itself can have any name. The information I'm missing is the Blocks ID (my column ElementID in the example). What I'm looking for is a way to get that ElementID. I found one, but in my eyes it doesn't seem to be very efficient... considering I will have approx 100 thousand of rows in the dataframe later

Comment: Are the IDs (Either elementID, nextBlockID, or prevBlockID) in lexicographer order? That is - would it be meaningful to so them? Or, is it just a double-linked list with no meaning to names?

Comment: Unfortunately the latter one

Comment: Then I see no alternative than to iterate over the list. One thing - it might be more efficient to create a data structure (not the data frame) on which you'll iterate.